# How to group set of controllers in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new iphone developer with experiences in web development , and now i try to build tabs in a controller , in HTML i use div to group set of controllers so I can hide or display it through JavaScript , how i can achieve the same thing in xcode ( interface builder ) ?

Comment: the fastest way is to use the tab bar application template in xcode

Comment: Yes but inside the tabs there is tabs ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a TabBar controller. Try to implement the code like this:

```
  myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  NewsFeedController *newsFeedController = [[NewsFeedController alloc] initWithFacebook:facebook];
  UINavigationController *navigationControllerHome = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsFeedController];
  [newsFeedController release];
  AboutController *aboutController = [[AboutController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *navigationControllerAbout = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutController];
  [aboutController release];
  myTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationControllerHome, navigationControllerAbout, nil];
  [self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
```

The NewsFeedController and AboutController will appear in tabs

Comment: @Some Guy on the Internet typing tabbar controller I didn't mean a name of class. Anyway editing my answer you should have at least type UITabBarController but not just TabBar controller....if you start editing do it proper way.

Comment: Feel free to edit it back or make it however you like -- it's your answer.  To my eye, "tabbar" looks like a word pronounced TAB-ar, and I thought TabBar would be easier to read and understand quickly (and easier to read than UITabBarController) for most people.